# Migrating Artifactory 3.2.0 to 5.3.0 System Export

Tags: artifactory

Is it possible to perform a system export on an Artifactory 3.2.0 instance and import it directly to 5.3.0?

The last upgrade attempt failed and the import.export logs reported "Found existing binary in the filestore for " for almost all of our artifacts.  My research indicates this is due to entries already existing in the BINARIES table of the DB.  However, the previous engineer has assured me that database was blank before performing the system import.

I intend on testing this process again but would like to know if importing a 3.2.0 export into 5.3.0 is even supported.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Are you installing a fresh instance of Artifactory and doing a full system import? Do you use the same filestore folder? Usually, when getting this message that means that the import process found the same actual file on the hard drive level, meaning that it doesn't need to re-deploy it but only to create a pointer to it on the database level. This is perfectly fine and can be ignored in case that you have your filestore folder full.